# Can I View Webmin executed commands?

Tags: linux, webmin

I find `webmin` a good source of learning new methods of doing things in Linux if we were able to **view the executed commands** behind any combinations done in the GUI, can we somehow view the executed commands?

Comment: You can always take a look at its [source code](https://github.com/webmin/webmin).

Comment: Sure, but it is impractical to keep the source code on a second window always, isn't there any direct method where we can simply view what happens in the background? (e.g. like almost any SQL workbench)